# Function field of genus zero with a prime of degree 2

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

I found this exercise on Rosen's book "Number Theory in Function Fields":

Let $F/K$ be a function field of genus zero and let $P$ be a prime of $F$ of degree $2$. Let $\{1, x, y\}$ be a basis for the Riemann-Roch space $\mathcal L(P)$ (you can show that the dimension is exactly 3 by using Riemann-Roch theorem). Show that $F=K(x,y)$.

My idea was to use the fact that $[F:K(x)]=2$ (I know this by theory), but then I can't prove that $y$ is not contained in $K(x)$. Is this the right approach? How would you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's still relevant, but I think I have a solution. I hope I did not make any mistake, and that it will be of any help to you.

Let's assume towards contradiction that $F(x)=F(x,y)=F(y)$ (By symmetry, if one of the equalities is not true, we finish by your argument). By the properties of the p-valuation $v_p$, we know that $\{1,x,y,x^2,y^2,xy\}\in L(2p)$. By Riemman-Roch the dimension of $L(2p)$ is 5. So we have a linear dependency,
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2y+a_3x^2+a_4y^2+a_5xy=0$$
The ring $F[T,U]$ is a UFD. So if we denote $f(T,U)=a_0+a_1T+a_2U+a_3T^2 +a_4U^2+a_5TU$, and if $f(T,U)$ is reducible, it must be factored to linear factors. But then by the previous equation we get a non-trivial linear dependency on $1,x,y$ (over $F$) which is impossible. So, $f$ is irreducible.

Now look at the polynomial $a_0+a_1x+a_3x^2+(a_2+a_5x)T+a_4T^2\in F(x)[T]$. If $a_4\neq 0$, it is irreducible, since it is a primitive, irreducible polynoimal over $F[x][T]$. If $a_4=0$, we may assume WLOG that $a_2+a_5x$ does not divide $a_0+a_1x+a_3x^2$. Other wise, we could devide the first equation to ge an equation of the form $b_0+b_1x+y=0$, which is impossible by the linear independence of $1,x,y$. Hence The polynomial above is still primitive and so is the minimal polynomial of $y$ over $F(x)$.

We split to 2 cases. If $a_3=0$, we may write:

$$a_0+a_1x+a_2y+a_5xy=0$$

As $a_5\neq 0$ (by linear independence of $1,x,y$) This gives us-

$$y=\frac{-a_1x-a_0}{a_2+a_5x}\Rightarrow v_p(y)=v_p(-a_1x-a_0)-v_p(a_2+a_5x)$$

As the $p$ valuation of $1,x$ are different, we know that $$v_p(\alpha+\beta x)=min(v_p(\alpha),v_p(\beta x))=min(0,-1)=-1$$
If $\alpha\neq 0$. So, we get $v_p(y)\geq -1+1=0$ - a contradiction.

So we may assume $a_3\neq0$. In this case, by the symmetry between $x$ and $y$ - we finish.

[Edit: I now noticed that I am using a different notation than you, taking $F$ to be the ground field.]

Comment: Could it happen that $K(x,y)$ is a proper subfield of $F$? I thought that is what the question was about.

Comment: A-priori, yes - but you know that $F/K(x)$ is an extension of dimension 2, so if you show that $y$ (which is an algebraic element over $K(x)$) is such that $K(x,y)/K(x)$ is of dimension 2, you finish. This should be correct even if my proof is not, as it is given as an exercise in Rosen's "Number Theory in Function Fields" (I am not sure I understand your question so please correct me if I didn't)

Comment: Oh yeah! I missed that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems correct to me. I only don't understand why you need to split into cases depending on $a_3$. Once you find the minimal polynomial for y has degree 2, don't you get the result?

Comment: It is the minimal polynomial, but we want it to be of degree 2, otherwise we don't finish. I tried to verify that when $a_4=0$, we always get a contradiction.

Perhaps there's a simpler way to do it :)